# UIPageViewController pages with different widths

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller

How can I have a `UIPageViewController` with pages having different widths?

The reason I'm doing this is because I want part of the next / previous page to show when I'm looking at a specific page, and I want the gap between them to be the same, so the width won't be.

Something like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

So assuming the screen width is `320`, the red view will have `272`, the green will have `256` and the blue will have `272`.

If we had only one page, then the view would have `288` as width.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle "preview paging" is to use a UICollectionView. I think this will be a better solution than having variable width pages in a UIPageViewController.

There are several ways to do this - I've seen SO posts about it but can't locate the exact ones I've used for reference.

I've implemented it in the past differently, but here is an example of the concept: http://blog.karmadust.com/centered-paging-with-preview-cells-on-uicollectionview/

Comment: Yeah, but the main reason I wanted `UIPageViewController` was because I wanted all it's features already implemented for me, like page handling with the snap to a specific page.